# React - problem using useContext & useReducer

Tags: reactjs, use-context, use-reducer

Hey I had a problem while using useContext (React Hooks) and useReducer (for store a array with 4 values of string). Explained in the pictures down below what exactly it's wrong and what I have done. Thank u

[image]
App.js - using ItemsByCategory (Line 7). using useContext for passing for Categories component object with 2 values - CategoriesArray and CategoriesDisaptch (Line 37-39)[image]
At categories component, I have a problem when adding the line of onClick function. Without it, works fine.
The error that showed for me, added as an image. [image]

Comment: Can you please include the code instead of a picture? In my case I'm unable to see the images because imgur.com is blocked on my work machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning `CategoriesArray` as `categories` in your `<ItemsByCategory.Provider/>`. So you have to do `CategoriesContext.categories.map(filterCategory)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

find my problem. At reducer function can't do - return;
I didn't want to update the categoriesArray - only want to display specific images according to their categories at setMenuItems function as I did - so return state in both cases. Added as a parameter for the func.